# Record user sessions using javascript to analyize it later using google analytics (offline)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am wondering if you can give me advice of whether it is possible to capture the user-seesions and interactions (buttons clicked hovered etc).

Later I want to evaluate the results using google analytics.

Comment: Do you mean you want to programmatically create events using js and send it to GA? I'm not sure why you'd want to use offline analytics for.

Comment: because i cannot use the online. my application is web based but running offline

Comment: You can capture events/hits using the offline tracker, but the device must connect online to get that data into GA.

Comment: What do you mean by 'and then play it'?  What Offline Google Analytics does is capture the user interaction, stores it in cache (indexDB) as a queue, and push them up to Google Analytics when a network is available.

Comment: indeed. i mean that the analytics will be done later when the network will be available

Answer (score 0):

Only in a very limited fashion.

There is a feature designed for apps that are sometimes (but not always) offline. It's called [queue time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt), and allows you to send and offset between the time the tracked event occured and the time you sent the hit to GA. This works reliably (per documentation) for up to an 4 hour offset - might work for longer offsets (has something to do with the timezone rollover in your account, a Google developer once said on SO that it *might* work for up to 24 hours), but less reliably. So if you are connected at least ever four hours you could store your hits somewhere and then send then via the measurement protocol with the queue time parameter set. You would however have to have send each request individually (well, almost - you can [batch up to 20 requests](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch)), there is no real bulk upload for hit data.

Apart from queue time you cannot set time or date information for hits, so there is no way to upload data outside the queue time scope and have it recorded for the time it actually occurred (and again there is not upload for hot data, you would need to send it request by request).